# How to send data to the chart using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, react-google-charts

I get some data using Node.js. And I have an HTML file with Google Chart. I want to send the info which I get in Node.js to the Google Chart in my HTML, so that when I open the page I can see the chart with info which I got in Node.js.

I don't have a clue how to do that. I need to show this data in the chart.  How can I send this data from a js file to the chart in the HTML file?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
    
        var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     10],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
            ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(tableData, options);
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

JS

```
const express = require("express");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();


app.get("/", function(req, res){

    const url = "https://api.caw.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/ukraine?strict=true";
    
    https.get(url, function(response){
        console.log(response.statusCode);

        response.on("data", function(data){
            const covidData = JSON.parse(data); 
            console.log(covidData.cases);
        })
    })
    res.send("Success");
})


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server is tunning on port 3000.");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a server in that case.

JS file (in the jquery document.ready function)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(chatStart);
    function chatStart(){
      jQuery.get("https://api.caw.sh/v3/covid-19/countries/ukraine?strict=true", 
         function(data,status){
   
         const arrayData = JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(arrayData);
          drawChart(arrayData)
       })
    }


      function drawChart(chartData) {
    
        var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(tableData, options);
      }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script src="../app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this could help you

Comment: Thank you, but the thing is that i need to show this data in the chart. I have data and I have a chart. How can i send this data from js file to the chart in HTML file?

Comment: You just need to put it on the HTML file inline script.
The code updated.
Please make sure that you modified the chardData based on your google chart style.

Answer (score 0):

So what you can do is have your google charts code inside a function which takes data as a parameter. Now call this function from your code with that data as input to the function.

Say your data in node js is an array of

```
chartData = [['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     10],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]]
```

Call the function to generate your google charts.

```
drawChart(chartData);
```

Now in your function to generate google charts, using the chartData array,

```
function drawChart(chartData) {

    var tableData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };
```

...

Something like this should help.

Comment: There is a problem. When I try to call the function in my js "drawChart(chartData);" it says that "ReferenceError: drawChart is not defined". It's because this function is in html file. I don't know how to get access to this function in html from js

Comment: Did you include your external JS file in your html?

Comment: Yes, with this line <script src="../app.js"></script> in my body html

Comment: If you can't call the drawchart function directly, can you return the array to html from app.js and then pass that to drawchart? That must work for sure.

Comment: I will be really pleased if you show me how to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042087/getting-data-from-node-js-file-and-displaying-it-in-html-js-page